# SQL how to create and import only specific columns from table A to a new table, table B

Tags: sql, toad

In Table A i have many fields like referenceid, amount, timestamp, remarks, status, balancebefore, balanceafter, frmsisdn, tomsisdn, id etc etc

I want to create a new table, Table B based of Table A(with column names, datatypes etc etc) but i only need specific columns that are in table A.

I tried select * into TableB from TableA where 1 = 2 but it says ORA-00905: missing keyword. I am using TOAD.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, the correct syntax is `create table as`.  `SELECT INTO` is used primarily in SQL Server and Sybase.

```
create table tableb as
    select . . .
    from tableA;
```

Only include the `where` clause if you don't actually want to insert any rows.

Comment: Will this only copy the columns or the whole data too? i dont need the data, i just need the columns.

Comment: @SaiAvinash . . . Then add the `where` clause as the answer suggests.

Comment: Awesome. Table was successfully created. thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL the syntax is the same as Oracle's (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html)).

Notice that the new table does not contain any constraints from the original table (indexes, keys, etc.)